# It is possible to open .html file located in add on resource (data directory)?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I want to have something like a 'result page' for an add-on, an own page of the add-on that will be open and display annotations and other result things. Ideally I would use an `.html` file located in the `data` directory of the add-on.

Does the `window` module provide the ability to open extension's own files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you will want to open a new tab, not a window. There is no problem opening pages from your `data` directory, you simply have to use the URL returned by [self.data.url()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/self#data.url%28name%29):

```js
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var self = require("sdk/self");
tabs.open({
  url: self.data.url("result-page.html"),
  inBackground: false,  // This can also be: inNewWindow: true
});
```

This page won't have any special privileges however. In particular, it won't have any access to your add-on's data and it won't be able to exchange messages with your add-on. For that you need to inject a content script into the newly open tab:

```js
tabs.open({
  url: self.data.url("result-page.html"),
  inBackground: false,
  onReady: function(tab)
  {
    tab.attach({
      contentScriptFile: self.data.url("result-page.js"),
      onMessage: function(message)
      {
        // Message from content script, send a response?
      }
    });
  }
});
```

See [tab.attach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#attach%28options%29) and [Communicating with content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Communicating_With_Other_Scripts).

Comment: I want you to know that I'm your fan. I often read your posts. You are very skilled in the browser add-ons.