# Firefox: activeTab getElementByID

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm writing a plugin for Firefox, and I want to modify the HTML page for that I've just created using the `Tabs.open("htmlDocument.html")` feature.

I know of the whole `document.getElementByID(xxx)`, but this does not work for my plugin.  Comes back with the error `'document is not defined'.`

There is as usual, a virtual beer in it!

Comment: This is a duplicate question to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528639/it-is-possible-to-open-html-file-located-in-add-on-resource-data-directory

Once the tab is opened, then you simply need to attach a script to the open tab, which will populate the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use form objects i.e use with(document.forms.form_name)
//acess your field here inside of curly braces instead of get element by ID